# Python: using "if not" on multiple items

Tags: python, if-statement, operators

Can I do this in Python:

```
if not (list1, list2, list3):
    ...
```

To check if all given lists are empty?

If not how else would I do it?

Comment: Your technique doesn't work because its a non-empty tuple of empty lists... but non-empty tuples are always "truthy".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A tuple that has at least one element is truthy in boolean context. This means that  `not (list1, list2, list3)` is always *False*.

Since empty lists are falsy, you can use the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#any) function as shown below

```
if not any([list1, list2, list3]):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if not (list1 + list2 + list3):
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
if not (list1 or list2 or list3):
```

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure this logic is wrong - "not" binds closer than "or".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if several variables are all None or False-like, you can do:

```
if not any(list1, list2, list3):
    print("All lists are empty")
```

However, this will not work for lists that contain all false-like values (`None`, `False`, `""`, `[]`, etc...). If you want to do that, you can do:

```
def allitems(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
            for y in allitems(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x

list1 = [None, [False], [False, [False, [None, False], False, None], [False, None]], False]
print(any(allitems(list1)))  # => False
```

This will work on recursive lists/tuples, too. It ensures that all values within them are False-like.

Answer (score 0):

The most fluent way to do it is to use the `all` higher-order function:

```
   if all(len(l) == 0 for l in (l1, l2, l3)):
        print "lists are empty"
```

This check is logically more correct as it states in a readable way what you mean.